# how to store a auth token in react native from api responce

Tags: react-native, jwt, authorization, token

i am trying to store the  response.data.token into sessionstorage or localstorage how can i do it from inside the `axios then`

```
   const getdata = async () => {
    var date2 = moment(mydate2).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    var date = moment(mydate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    var todaydate = moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    if (date == todaydate && date2 != todaydate) {
      var Data56 = {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        babyname: babyname,
        phone: nuber,
        period: date2,
        // baby_date: date,
      };
    } else {
      var Data56 = {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        babyname: babyname,
        phone: nuber,
        // period: date2,
        baby_date: date,
      };
    }

    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register',
      data: Data56,
    })
      .then(async response => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', `${response.data.token}`);
        alert('sucess ');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
      });
  };
```

[image]

i am trying to store the  response.data.token into sessionstorage or localstorage how can i do it from inside the `axios then`

Comment: you can use AsyncStorage: https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage

Comment: @darshilsakhiya  i tryed  AsyncStorage but it does not work inside axios

Comment: Which error did you get when you are using AsyncStorage inside axios?

Comment: @darshilsakhiya i have added the error and updated the question what i tryed with AsyncStorage

Comment: are you getting perfect responses from API? first please check with `console.log`.

Comment: yes i am gettinbg respomce perfety

Answer (score 0):

==>  Update Your code like this:-

```
    .then(function async(response) {
    try{
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
    }catch{
       console.log("Catch Function")
    }
```

Comment: yes i have tryed this too i gat the same error

Comment: @jisaks i have updated my answer please check it and let me know.

Comment: 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.ts(1308)

Comment: i am getting thsis error when used ur code

Comment: @jisaks Okay Understood, now when ever your function is defined for the API calls make it async and let me know.

Comment: i not sure how to do that can u help with that

Comment: @jisaks Sure, First Where are you define this Axios code, in the function or what, can you please share some more code?

Comment: i have added more code for ur convienece

Comment: @jisaks are you still getting same error..?

Comment: i fixed by importing AsyncStorage

Answer (score 0):

Setting data to Asyncstorage works asynchronous so you need set with await like this:

```
axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register',
      data: Data,
 
    })
   .then(async (response) => {
         
       await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', `${response.data.token}`);
         alert("sucess ");
   
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
      });
  }
```

Comment: i am geting same error as screnshot the issue is that when ever i add   `AsyncStorage` in then   the api call is scucess but the `catch` of axios is running

Comment: can you print your response to console?

Comment: `.catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        // alert(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
      });`   i got this error `ReferenceError: AsyncStorage is not defined`

Comment: Did you import AsyncStorage?

Comment: the error was not importing AsyncStorage but now i get warnng `AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from @react-native-community/async-storage instead of 'react-native'.` should i worry about it

Comment: Yes, AsyncStorage is used with this library `@react-native-community/async-storage` try installing this one and let me know your error

Comment: i dont see documentiaon for installing react-native-community/async-storage

Comment: Previous one was the extracted one try installing this `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` and you can find docs from here `https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage`